# Block Insertion Cursor Style in Tkinter Entry Widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, cursor-position

The tkinter text widget has a `blockcursor` option, which makes the default insertion cursor into a block insertion cursor. This is the sort of insertion cursor style used in command lines. I would like to replicate this style in a tkinter entry widget.

The issue I am having is that there is no such `blockcursor` option for a tkinter entry widget. The only alternative I have found is changing the `insertwidth` of the entry widget, but that leaves the insertion cursor centered between two characters and covers half of the character to the left and right of the insertion cursor. Ideally, I would like a block insertion cursor styling that covers the entirety of a character. Is there another way to go about this or perhaps a way to offset the cursor so that it covers a whole character?

Any help would be much appreciated.

And if it is any aid, below is the farthest I have come with my entry widget configurations:

```python
inputentry = Entry(self.root, bg = 'black', fg = '#00ff00', width = 60)
inputentry.config(font='Courier', insertbackground = '#00ff00', highlightthickness = 0)
inputentry.config(relief = 'flat', insertwidth = 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there another way to go about this or perhaps a way to offset the cursor so that it covers a whole character?

No, there is not. The options you mentioned in the question are all that are available with respect to the insertion cursor.